# How to get all the table names and distinct values in a particular column from a database for the tables which have a column using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get all the table names and the values present in a particular column if the column is present in the database. For the tables without the column ignore those.

For example: Find all the table name and values from a column 'last_refresh_date' in a database for all the tables with last_refresh_date column.

The code I tried is:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT distinct ''?'' TableName, last_refresh_date FROM ?'
```

I get an error as some of the tables doesn't have the column name 'last_refresh_date' in it.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I suppose my first question is *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm also *sure* I answered a question *very* similar to this in the past few days, but i can't find it.

Comment: I am trying to create a table that has all the table names in the database together with the last date on which the table was refreshed as per a column last_refresh_date present in most of the tables in db.The last_refresh_date only have a value per table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to *assume* you are using a recent version of SQL Server, and thus have access to `STRING_AGG`, if not you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method.

Anyway, you achieve this with a little bit of dynamic SQL, and `UNION ALL`. I assume you want the table and schema names as well:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @ColumnName sysname = N'YourColumnName',
        @CRLF nchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(30) = @CRLF + N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS SchemaName, N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName, ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]), @Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.object_id)
            FROM sys.schemas s
                 JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                 JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            WHERE c.[name] = @ColumnName)

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```